# Excel formula to check if previous column has N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am after a function that checks if 8 consecutive values are all greater than the average of the data (C29) and then return the last cell in the array of 8 if this is true. I have a working formula, which is

```
=IF(D38>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D38>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D39>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D40>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D41>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D42>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D43>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D44>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D45>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D46>$C$29,NA(),D46)))))))))))))))))))
```

However now I would like to add another test to this: if the corresponding cell in the column before it (I46) contains N/A, then I would like it to return the value of the formula above. But, if I46 contains a value, then I would like this cell to return N/A. I am struggling to wrap my head around how I can put this in, and whether to put it at the start or the end of the nested IF.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following template:

```
=IF(ISNA(I46),formula that you already have,NA())
```

Which would be:

```
=IF(ISNA(I46),IF(D38>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D38>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D39>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D40>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D41>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D42>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D43>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D44>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D45>$C$29,NA(),(IF(D46>$C$29,NA(),D46))))))))))))))))))),NA())
```

I haven't tested this, but am taking at face value your statement that the formula you have now does what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Another quick question - how would I test for if 2 cells had NA? Thanks, Stella.

Comment: `AND(ISNA(A1),ISNA(B1))` tests if both A1 and B1 are NA. Replace `AND` by `OR` to test if at least one of them is NA.